# Getting reason for crash by using Release mode binary in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there any chance of getting the reason for crash in my application(Windows), using release mode exe. I have used debug mode exe to get call stack or mini dump kind of things. As using debug mode exe is not the recommended way, can't use debug mode exe. I'm using multithreaded application and failing to get the exact reason behind the crash.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

Platform being used is C++.

Comment: You should post the linker and compiler options used in your project, and the crash log if any.

Comment: @prabindh I'm using VS2010(C++) and enabled debug info and some more options in project, as suggested in some web sites. I want the initial steps to proceed.

Comment: @Naveen08 Do you have logs in your application, maybe you can use that? Did you try to build in release mode with debug info and then attach to a process using VS?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Sorry we have logs but we have to know the place where exactly the application has crashed(In case of Access Violation, Stack overflow, array bound). And also the application is being running in customer environment, so we cannot attach and debug the issue. I want to know the place where exactly the application got crashed in release mode without deploying the .pdb files (Debug information) into customer environment, and using release mode binary, such as getting callstack or minidump automatically once the application has crashed.

Comment: Kindly anybody help me to get a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

In the release mode the location of the process' memory differs from the location in debug mode. If you have such a behavior then I assume you have some memory issues. Let me propose you some strategy... 1) Static code analysis + code review. 2) Introduce your own memory allocator to guard the dynamic memory. Upon deallocation the guards need to be checked against corruption. Once such one is detected, you need to identify which SW operated with this chunk of memory (by the chunk size, use case, content upon deallocation....). Following this you have a chance to identify a suspect in the SW.

Comment: Instead of (badly) reinventing the wheel just use valgrind for #2.